# Proving a group, $G$, is a group action onto some set, $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I want to prove that a function defines a group action:

> We have group $G$ of diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices under matrix multiplication, and the set $X$ of points of the Cartesian plane, eg:
>
> $G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a &0\\0&b \end{bmatrix} : a,b\in \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right\}$, $X=\{(x,y): x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$
>
> For each $g =\begin{bmatrix} a &0\\0&b \end{bmatrix}\in G$ and $(x,y)\in X$ where I use minus to denote that $0\not\in$ this set, define the function
>
> $g((x,y)) = (ax,by)$

How to prove closure, identity and composition? Refer [to edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/919040/revisions) for effort shown. Question de-cluttered so people won't deem it too much effort.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a function defines a group action." What's the group you're working with, and what set is it supposed to be acting on, and how is this function you mention related to the group and the set?

Comment: What does that mean? Do you have a function $G\times X\to X$ for some group $G$ and set $X$, and you want to know what it means to prove this function defines a group action?

Comment: Okay. Let's say you are *starting* with a function $G\times X\to X$, or equivalently a function $g:X\to X$ associated to each $g\in G$. Then closure is immediate, since the codomain is $X$. (In your reasoning I don't understand what $a$ is, or what $ax$ is supposed to mean.) For identity, you indeed show that $e(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$, where $e\in G$ is the identity. And for composition, you show $f(g(x))=(f\cdot g)(x)$, where $\cdot$ is the group operation in $G$ and $f,g\in G$.

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, your question should have been phrased something like "I have a function $G\times X\to X$, and I want to know what it means for this to define a group action, and how to test it in practice. Is my understanding of these three tests (closure, identity, composition) correct?" By the way, users are free to post homework questions, as long as they don't omit important details and explain all of their thoughts, ideas, work, etc. Indeed it would probably be better if you include the original problem(s) so we can help you better.

Comment: If the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive then there is a bijection between $X$ and $G/H$ for some subgroup $H$ (the stabilizer of one of the points of $X$). The action then boils down to the action of $G$ on the cosets of a subgroup $H$ as follows $g(uH)=(gu)H$.

Comment: composition has to hold for arbtrary elements $g_1$, $g_2\in A$. You have only checked the case $g_1 = g_2$ ($=g$, in your proof)

Comment: I have removed ([tag:finite-groups]) tag, since the group in the question is infinite. (If I have misunderstood something and there is some reason to have this tag in the question, feel free to edit it back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if we work with column vectors, the group action you described is just the multiplication of matrices.

$$g(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax \\ by \end{pmatrix}$$

Now the fact that this is indeed a [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) follows from the well-known properties of matrix multiplication:

- *Closure:* If we multiply $2\times 2$ and $2\times 1$-matrix, we get again $2\times 1$-matrix.
- *Identity:* Multiplication by the identity matrix does not change anything.
- *Compatibility* is a consequence of associativity of matrix multiplication.

---

Another possibility how to look at this problem is to view it as the [coordinatewise multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) of 2-dimensional vectors. (If you identify the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ with the vector $(a,b)$.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense, I imagine this was the intended interpretation!

Answer (score 2):

You might have seen that a group action $G \times X \to X$ is actually *the same things* as a group morphism $G \to \operatorname{Bij}(X)$. Namely, for a group action $\varphi \colon G \times X \to X$, the group morphism is $\psi \colon g \mapsto \varphi(g,\cdot)$ ; conversely, any group morphism $\psi \colon G \to \operatorname{Bij}(X)$ gives rise to a group action $\varphi \colon (g,x) \mapsto \psi(g)(x)$.

Here, viewing $2\times 2$-matrices as linear endomorphisms of the plane, the inclusion $i \colon G \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Bij}(\mathbb R^2)$ is a group morphism giving rise to the group action $(g,(x,y)) \mapsto i(g)(x,y) = g(x,y)$ which is precisely the function of the exercise.

---

Remark that here the image of the inclusion $i$ is actually included in the group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb R^2)$ of linear automorphisms of the plane, not only in the group of set-theoretic bijections. It is what we call a (faithful here) *linear representation* of the group $G$. Representation theory is a beautiful theory, you can look it up if you are curious.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It appears to be a little more complex than the alternative answer, so I will spend some time understanding it and will ask you questions later. I appreciate your efforts!